# Is there a way to insert the filename into the record when importing a JSON file into Power BI?

Tags: json, powerbi

Not sure how to ask this but here goes. I have a collection of 500+ JSON files that I need to import into PowerBI. Each JSON has four different levels of information that I need to parse out. I converted the JSON top-level info into a table and transposed it so I had one row like the attached screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NEwR.png)

My first question is: can I easily add the filename to the JSON record? I would like to use the filename as a unique key in later queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be connecting to each JSON file individually?  If I'm correct, assuming all the JSON files can be in a single folder, you can use the "Folder" connection.  That then allows you to right-click on the original folder query and choose "reference" to then create various transformations for each JSON file, and it includes the file name.

Related details:
https://powerbi.tips/2016/06/loading-data-from-folder/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-referenced-queries

Hoping that helps!